# The current path of a macOS application

Tags: c++, windows, macos, qt

On Windows I used to put files, like a `config.ini`, on the same directory as the executable.

But now I porting an application to macOS an looks like I have to shift path 3 levels up `../../../config.ini`.

Is there any variable the points to the place on both OSs?

Comment: Is this a read-only file?  Or do you intend for it to be edited either by the application or the user directly?

Comment: Let's consider the application will read/write to this file (the user might edit it as well since is pure text), might be used by `QSettings`. Why?

Comment: Note that the MacOS/X executable is inside the MyApplication.app/Contents/MacOS folder.  Presumably you want to place your config.ini file in the same folder that MyApplication.app is present in, hence the three-levels-up.

Comment: That's the point, I think I don't want `config.ini` inside there. Seems like I want it outside the package and a variable that point there. Will this be a weird choice? Perhaps I should just copy `config.ini` inside?

Comment: When the application starts, read from the user's home folder: `~/.yourappname/config.ini`  If the file is not there, write a reasonable default set of config options in that location.

Comment: "*On Windows I used to put files ... on the same directory as the executable*" - that is not a good idea. Many paths outside of the user's profile are not writable to non-admin users. You should instead write the file in a subfolder within the user's profile. For instance, use)SHGetFolderPath()` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` to get the path to the user's (local) APPDATA folder, then create a subfolders in it, then save your file in there.

Comment: are you storing configuration files ?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 1):

Your Guide for Deploying Qt Applications to MacOS

https://www.ics.com/blog/your-guide-deploying-qt-applications-macos

https://forum.qt.io/topic/59209/solved-osx-deployment-fatal-error-with-dylib-library-not-loaded-image-not-found/4